# combine 2 select statement with different where clause sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i want combine 2 select with different where clause
first select is

```
SELECT name,
   COUNT(telat_1_30min)
FROM kkpsurabaya
WHERE telat_1_30min >= 1
AND telat_1_30min <= 30;
```

the result is:

```
name         | telat1 1-30 min
FERI WAHYUDI | 2
```

and other select is

```
SELECT COUNT(late) AS 'telat 31-60min'
FROM kkpsurabaya
WHERE timetable NOT LIKE 'minggu'
AND timetable NOT LIKE 'sabtu'
AND late <= 90
AND late >= 61;
```

and result is :

```
name         | telat1 31-60 min
KARIYONO     | 1
```

i want combine that like

```
name         | telat1 1-30 min|telat1 31-60 min
FERI WAHYUDI | 2              |0
KARIYONO     | 0              |1
```

i try use query

```
SELECT name,
       'telat < 30menit' = (SELECT
         COUNT(telat_1_30min) AS 'telat 1-30min'
       FROM kkpsurabaya
       WHERE telat_1_30min >= 1
       AND telat_1_30min <= 30),
       'telat 31-60 min' = (SELECT
         COUNT(late) AS telat_60_90
       FROM kkpsurabaya
       WHERE timetable NOT LIKE 'minggu'
       AND timetable NOT LIKE 'sabtu'
       AND late <= 90
       AND late >= 61)
FROM kkpsurabaya
GROUP BY Name;
```

and the result is:

```
name         | telat1 1-30 min|telat1 31-60 min
FERI WAHYUDI | 2              |1
KARIYONO     | 2              |1
```

telat_1_30min type data is int

late type data is int

solved

`select name
,sum (case when  telat_1_30min >=1 and telat_1_30min <=30  then 1 else 0 end) as 'telat1 1-30 min'
,sum(case when  timetable not like 'minggu' and timetable not like 'sabtu' and late <=90 and late >=61 then 1 else 0 end ) as 'telat1 31-60 min'
from kkpsurabaya 
group by name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select  name, count( telat_1_30min)  as ' telat1 1-30 min',0 as 'telat1 31-60 min'
    from kkpsurabaya where  telat_1_30min >=1 and telat_1_30min <=30 
    union all
    SELECT name,0 as  ' telat1 1-30 min', count(late) as 'telat 31-60min' 
    FROM kkpsurabaya WHERE timetable not like 'minggu' and timetable not like 'sabtu' and late <=90 and late >=61
```

Edit

```
select
a.name
,sum(telat1 31-60 min) as 'telat1 1-30 min'
,sum(telat1 31-60 min) as 'telat1 31-60 min'
(
select name
,case when  telat_1_30min >=1 and telat_1_30min <=30  then 1 else o end as 'telat1 1-30 min'
,case when  timetable not like 'minggu' and timetable not like 'sabtu' and late <=90 and late >=61 then 1 else 0 end as 'telat1 31-60 min'
from timetable 
)a
group by a.name
```

Comment: hmm that show only with name have value how i can show to name without value? i mean if they telat 1-30 = 0 and 31-60 = 0

Comment: what is ,sum(telat1 31-60 min) as 'telat1 1-30 min'
,sum(telat1 31-60 min) as 'telat1 31-60 min' that eror there , i dont have column telat1 31-60 min